# python notation form textbook

Tags: python, syntax, pseudocode

I have a code snipped from my algorithms text book and i'm have a hard time understanding it.

```
K(0) = 0
for w = 1 to W
    K(w) = max{K(w - w_i)+vi:w_i<=w}
return K(W)
```

i'm confused as to whats happening on line 3 what does the colon mean here? can this be written in a different way?

Comment: what are they doing with it?

Comment: This doesn't look like python

Comment: That's pseudocode, not Python.

Comment: any idea what its doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like python. It seems that K is supposed to be an array, but indices are indicated by square brackets in python, so `K[0] = 0`

And the `for w = 1 to W` doesn't work in python at all, it would be more like this: `for w in range(1, W+1):`

As for what the pseudo code does: It looks like for each element of K, it calculates the maximum of all previous values and adds vi.

```
for w in range(1, W+1):
    K[w] = max(K[w - w_i] + vi for w_i in range(1, w+1))
```

But vi doesn't seem to change, so for positive vi, this produces simply a linearly ascending array (i.e. `[0, 2, 4, 6, ...` for `vi = 2`), and for negative it just repeats vi over and over: `[0, -3, -3, -3, ...` for `vi = -3`

Since it returns only the last value of the array, it could be simplified to

```
return W*vi if vi>0 else vi
```